# Searchable Symmetric Encryption VS Deterministic encryption?

Tags: encryption, symmetric, deterministic-encryption, searchable-encryption

I am a beginner learning about encryption. The Searchable Symmetric Encryption is better than Deterministic encryption? When I say better I mean smaller leakage.

Answer (score 1):

Comparision is not possible between Searchable Symmetric Encryption (SSE) and Deterministic Encryption (DE). The reason is given below:

DE is an encryption scheme with the property that it always generates the same ciphertext for the same message. Hence, this is more prone to Guessing Attacks.
Examples of DE are Unpadded RSA, AES with ECB mode, and Order Preserving Encryption etc.

SSE is Crypto paradigm that facilitates searching over the encrypted data. You can use DE as an encryption scheme in SSE for encrypting the data and then make it searchable with the help of searchable indexes. However, the output of this SSE could be more prone to Guessing Attacks because DE was used in SSE.